# GridLayout null margins

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, flowlayout

I put several JPanels, each containing a JLabel + JTextField in a GridLayout (as shown below).
I am trying to reduce the spaces between the cells as much as possible.
I did the following :

```
GridLayout resultsPanelLt = new GridLayout( 0, 3, 0, 0 );
resultsPanelLt.setVgap( 0 );
resultsPanelLt.setHgap( 0 );
JPanel resultPanel =  new JPanel( resultsPanelLt );

// I added several panels like this one
JPanel markUpPanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.RIGHT ));
markUpPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(100, 20) );
markUpPanel.setMaximumSize( new Dimension(100, 20) );
markUpPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
markUpPanel.add( new JLabel( "MarkUp" ) );
JTextField markUp = new JTextField();
markUp.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
markUpPanel.add( markUp );

resultPanel.add( markUpPanel );
```

[image: I would like to remove the spaces between rows]
I would like to remove the spaces between rows or put them to 1px for instance.

Comment: new GridLayout( 0, 3, 0, 0 ) why do you use 0 rows?

Comment: 1) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 3) Instead `pack()` is our friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create and add panels to your `resultPanel` which has `GridLayout`, the child panels are created with `FlowLayout`. Those child panels have 5 pixel horizontal and vertical gaps.

Create those like this:

```
JPanel markUpPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 0));
```

The `FlowLayout` class has a constructor where you can specify the horizontal and veritcal gaps, pass 0 pixel to those. If you don't specify them, the default is 5 pixel.